# Shared lock for Python objects

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I'm developing a tiny web application with Flask/Gunicorn on Heroku. Since I'm just prototyping, I have a single web process (dyno) with a worker thread started by the same process. The web application is just returning a JSON dump of a global object, which is periodically updated by the worker thread monitoring an external web service. The global object is updated every 15 to 60 minutes. My plan was to use an exclusive lock in the worker thread when an update to the global object is needed, and a shared lock in the web threads so multiple requests can be satisfied concurrently. Unfortunately it looks like that Python doesn't have shared locks, only exclusive locks. How can I ensure consistency in the web threads, i.e., how to be sure that the update to the global object is atomic while allowing multiple read-only access to the object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python : Any way to get one process to have a write lock and others to just read on parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261902/python-any-way-to-get-one-process-to-have-a-write-lock-and-others-to-just-read)

Comment: @univerio thanks for the heads-up. Yes, the solutions there apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the updates are so infrequent, you're better off just making a copy of the object, updating copy, and then updating the global variable to point to the new object.  Simple assignments in python are atomic so you don't need any locks at all.

Comment: I thought about that, but since the object has many properties, it's still possible that the update occurs while one web thread is reading them, so the web thread gets part of the properties of the old object and part of the properties of the updated object.

Comment: That does not happen with the scheme I am describing.  You have a global variable.  You never update the object that the global variable points to.  You copy the object that the global variable points to.  This copy must copy anything that you intend to update.  `copy.deepcopy` would be safe.  You then update the private copy, and finally publish the new copy as the the global shared thing by swapping the variable.  Readers copy the global variable to a temporary.  The object that the temporary points to will never get touched.  This is basically RCU.

Comment: Make sense now?  If so, I'll update the original post.