# What are the equivalents of read-write locks in Python and equivalents for atomic data types in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, concurrency

Python seems to only have exclusive locks, but that is not a good choice when I protect some data where I want allow multiple reader threads to read some critical data at same time, while exclusive access to only one thread to modify the data. 
The GIL Python doesn't allow multiple interpreter threads to execute at the same time. But still read-write locks would have been a great addition.

Also, atomic data types (such as atomic integer, atomic boolean) are really useful. For example, I may want to keep a variable for recording the size of data processed from some function, when the function is called from multiple threads and multiple times concurrently. An atomic integer or long perfectly fits the  bill, and relieves us from the expensive lock operations. Java has them, C++ has them, Go has them; I wish we will have them in Python as well.

Comment: "expensive lock operations" - if your performance requirements are such that locking is considered expensive, Python probably isn't the language for the job.

Comment: @user2357112  You are correct. Python was a bad choice for the my current project. Python concurrency is not good at all. But a lot of code is written in Python already for the current project I am working on. Moving all of them to C/C++/Go/Java will be an uphill task and not an option now. I am using Celery in pre-forked mode, but it has its own disadvantages.

Comment: There are is a read-write implements and some links to other implementations at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261902/python-any-way-to-get-one-process-to-have-a-write-lock-and-others-to-just-read

Comment: The whole reason for read write locks is concurrent access. Which loses most of its justification when you can't have that anyhow. Well it'd allow you lower latency at the cost of throughout but that doesn't strike me as something you'd want. Also you've profiled the code and found out that the lock was the biggest performance killer? When working on performance measures the same holds in every language: first measure then do something, everything else is pointless.