# 'Asymmetric' semaphore in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore

I have a situation where an object has many "modify" methods and one "push current state" method. Any combination of the "modify" methods may be running concurrently with no issues (other than concurrent alterations of the same specific property being undefined) but they can't be concurrent with the "push" method.

Is there a way to implement a semaphore so that any number of "modify" methods may acquire it, but the "push" method blocks until it is empty and "modify" methods block until "push" releases it?

Comment: What multithreading implementation are you using? This sounds roughly like a read/write lock.

Comment: Python's standard library `threading` module.

Comment: Looks like this might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261902/python-any-way-to-get-one-process-to-have-a-write-lock-and-others-to-just-read

Comment: Do both your `modify` and `push` make writes? If not, why are you calling them `modify` and `push` respectively? And if so, how do you expect simultaneous write (i.e. `modify`) operations to run fine? Asking because I am genuinely confused and would appreciate the clarification .

Comment: @Akshat Mahajan The object in question is an abstract representation of a graphical window; the "modify" methods "queue up" drawing operations, and the "push" actually draws them on the user's screen. So the modify methods write to the object, and the push method writes the object to output.