# Multiple return values from a Python function?

Tags: python

I have a front-end that continuously polls a python function. In the most simple form, the python function looks like this:

```
def some_func():
    new_list = []
    sleep(3)
    new_list.append(1)
    sleep(3)
    new_list.append(2)
    sleep(3)
    new_list.append(3)

    return new_list
```

Polling this function from the front-end results with me always getting the following list:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

What I'm curious about is if there is a way to return the list just as it is being modified? So at every 100 milliseconds the front-end will poll the back-end, and fetch the latest list. This should result in the following return values:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Can this be achieved with threading, Queue, etc.?

Comment: Yes, you can share objects between co-routines.  There are various techniques for doing that; you would need to do a little more research on the topic to determine what fits your specific application.  Since we don't know the characteristics you need, this is up to you for now.

Comment: If you have no further info, then you likely have an application that's just as simple as you described.  Rather than reinventing the wheel, I linked (in my answer) to a prior answer for most (all) of what you need, in a fully formal design.  I fall you have is one writer and a reader that checks whenever it wants to, then just use a shared parent variable.

Answer (score 1):

The list would need to be anchored in a context outside this routine.  Pass in the empty list from the parent program.  That parent also spawns the "listener" (design pattern) or other monitor routine -- and the same object reference would get passed to the listener.

That should give you a starting point.  Look up data sharing among co-routines, and see which particular characteristics you need in your sharing.  If you have merely a single routine that changes the data (writer), but one or more that examine the contents (readers), then you have a very well-documented general solution.

I strongly recommend that you write a class to "own" the data, with read/write methods.  Make an instance at your top level of design, and pass that instance to the functions that will deal with it.

Start with the readers/writers solutions linked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261902/python-any-way-to-get-one-process-to-have-a-write-lock-and-others-to-just-read#16262688) question.